# Running a full Java EE application (not just Webprofile) on minimal tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jpa, transactions

I would need your advice/opinion if I can run a full Java EE 6 application, which uses JPA, transaction services, DI etc. on minimal Tomcat if I distribute a Java EE 6 reference SDK (one which comes with Glassfish) as part of my application.

I am trying to experiment if I can use the Java EE 6 same way as people use the Spring. Where ever I go, I take my application and container I have tested on.

If doable, do you see any issue with this approach? Ofcourse, I understand that this practice is not aligned with the vision Java EE specs are created with but I feel sometimes even after all promises, things may go worse when porting application from on application server to another.

Thanks to everybody for taking time to read and reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that this practice is not aligned with the vision Java EE specs are created

I'm not entirely sure that this is fully the case. Sure, the main thing that Java EE defines are clear profiles that require a specific set of technologies to be all available. This has the big advantage that applications or libraries targeting Java EE can just assume that things like Bean Validation and CDI to just name two technologies are Just There.

But on the other hand nearly all of the sub-specs that make up Java EE can also be used individually outside Java EE. In a number of specifications (e.g. JPA) it's even explicitly defined how it should work in Java SE (in this case Tomcat counts as Java SE). In some other cases (e.g. CDI) it's currently a property of a specific implementation (e.g. Weld) that it works in Java SE.

And some other specifications (e.g. JSF) have as a rule of thumb that it should also work on the Servlet spec that's one version less than the version of the Servlet spec of Java EE in which that specification version introduced. E.g. JSF 2.0 is part of Java EE 6, which has Servlet 3.0, but it HAS to work with Servlet 2.5 as well. As far as I know this is not really done so older Java EE servers can upgrade just JSF, but mostly for people running older Tomcat versions.

All this compatibility with Java SE/Tomcat is done by the very people who also create the vision of the Java EE spec and who actually write and implement said spec.

> I am trying to experiment if I can use the Java EE 6 same way as people use the Spring.

There's no definite answer here, but you can get quite far by "simply" adding all of the implementation jars to the WEB-INF/lib directory if a war. E.g. the Weld jars for CDI, the Hibernate jars for JPA, the Mojarra jars for JSF, OpenEJB for EJB, etc.

The problem with this approach is that -YOU- will be responsible of making sure all those jars work together without issues.

The technologies may also not work as great together as they work in an out of the box "distribution" of Java EE; meaning that maybe injection doesn't work in all artifacts that you expect it to work, or maybe you have to provide extra configuration (e.g. tell Hibernate what the JTA transaction manager is, or configure a Filter to activate CDI on a request basis and another filter to activate JAX-RS, etc).

Yet another issue is that many Java EE technologies do some kind of annotation scanning. In Java EE implementations this can be done globally in one pass, but lacking any specific standard service for this each technology has to do this individually in "Java SE mode". This means the same jars will be scanned over and over again. Also not nice here is that depending on which implementations you exactly use you can end up with a lot of extra jars in WEB-INF/lib. These too will be scanned for annotation. In a Java EE implementation only the application jars will be scanned for each deployment.

Finally some Java EE things are not available separately, e.g. JASPIC and as far as I know JACC and JCA are not available as standalone implementations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining this in detail... so I understand at least I may need to take care of the glu code which is responsible for interaction between various JARs and JAVA SE (Tomcat) and JARs.. In an efficient way.

Comment: You're welcome ;) Implementing the glue code yourself is based on the various SPIs that the technologies define. While it's doable to build your own stack out of separate jars and configuring it, implementing the glue/integration code yourself is probably not an option for most people. It's basically akin to building your own AS (like e.g. TomEE).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a developer, but if i am correct a complete stack of Java EE cannot be run on Tomcat as it is just a Servlet Container and its not a application server as that of JBoss or WebLogic.

Comment: @Kannan - Agreed... so would like to know if its possible to distribute the JEE 6 API implementation (Application Server - Servlet Container) with my code (say in my EAR's lib) and to deploy on tomcat... generally what we do with Spring... in other words can the JEE 6 API implementations JARs can bridge the gap between Application Server and Servlet Container?

Comment: just to rephrase - the API implementation for Glassfish would work on other application servers or it's tightly bound with Glassfish?

Comment: Mostly that will not be doable or it might require a huge task of modifying tomcat itself. Are you facing any problem with using Application servers like glassfish, jboss ?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do just use TomEE
http://tomee.apache.org/